# Insert new first thead row of a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this table:

```
<table id="test">
<thead>
<tr><td>Main Head 1</td><td>Main Head 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Head 1</td><td>Sub Head 2</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I like to insert a new first row in the `thead` so it looks like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><td colspan="2">HEADING</td>/tr>
    <tr><td>Main Head 1</td><td>Main Head 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sub Head 1</td><td>Sub Head 2</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am using jQuery, I tried:

```
 var cln = $('#test').clone();
 cln.prepend('<tr><th>HEADING</th></tr>');
```

But it puts it in the first row of the body.

Comment: Your question says you want to insert a row, but the first thing the code does is create a clone, why?  Do you actually want a a separate, 2nd copy of your table (a clone)?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert your element above the thead, use child selector to insert inside the thead.

```js
$("#test > thead").prepend("<tr><td colspan='2'>Heading</td></tr>")
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main Head 1</td>
      <td>Main Head 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sub Head 1</td>
      <td>Sub Head 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find()`, find `thead` inside your cloned element,  and use `prepend` whatever you want to prepend.

Example:

```js
var cln = $('#test').clone();
cln.find('thead').prepend('<tr><th>HEADING</th></tr>');
$('#divClone').append(cln);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Main Head 1</td>
      <td>Main Head 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sub Head 1</td>
      <td>Sub Head 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<div id='divClone'></div>
```